# unable to clear textbox.text

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a textbox called txtNote. When I enter some text I click a save button and contents are written the database. I now want to clear the textbox value, so I had been using txtNote.text = "" but it no longer works as the save button is now part an update panel trigger.

E.g.

```
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNote" runat="server" CssClass="textarea full" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Button ValidationGroup="valgroup1" ID="btnNoteSave" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlNotes" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="content_container" style="margin-top: 85px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNoteSave" EventName="click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnNoteSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNoteSave.Click
    If txtNote.Text <> "" Then
        Dim newnote As New note()
        newnote.LoggedBy = Session("user_id")
        newnote.Note = txtNote.Text
        newnote.Create()
        txtNote.Text = "" 'this is not working.
        Dim note As New note()
        lblNotes.Text = note.shownotes(Val(txtTicketID.Value))

    End If

End Sub
```

I'm guessing it's not working as it's not able to do proper postback as an update panel is involved.

Any ideas how to get round this probably simple prob?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `TextBox` in its own `UpdatePanel`. Make sure to either set the `UpdateMode` to `Always`, or add the `Button` to the `Triggers` of the new `UpdatePanel`

Comment: That may work, but I wouldn't recommend adding any more Update Panel than you need. Your page can get really bloaty really quickly.

Comment: True, but if you need to update a control not in your `UpdatePanel` this is how you do it. That was what he asked, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNoteSave" EventName="click" />
                    </Triggers>
```

To:

```
<Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNoteSave" />
                    </Triggers>
```

EDIT:
Just noticed that the button is outside of the updatepanel. Not 100% sure if my suggestion will work.

Comment: Even if it did, it would just force the whole page to post back, which is almost assuredly not what he wants.

Comment: thanks, but yes don't really want the whole page to post back or was trying to avoid that if poss.

Comment: @drdwilcox I thought he would need to postback in order to hit the code-behind and clear the the TextBox's text.